# Framework Search Paths - Mixing $(inherited) with $(PROJECT_DIR)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS project in XCode 11.2 that requires a mix of Frameworks, some of which are available on Cocoapods and some are not.  For the non-Cocoapod frameworks, I have the frameworks copied to the root of my project folder.

The trouble comes with getting XCode to be able to find both using the Framework Search Paths setting as shown here:

[image]

All of the entries following $(inherited) are actually the ones inherited from Cocoapods (these are not explicitly specified).

If I don't add the $(PROJECT_DIR) at the end then Cococapod frameworks are found fine, but my embedded non-Cocoapod frameworks get compiler errors that their header files are not found.

If I do add the $(PROJECT_DIR) at the end, then the Cocoapod frameworks are not found and I get a build error like:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/dyoung/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acdmyjbbrpbhlkfiyypetovwacrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AWSAuthCore'
...
ld: framework not found AWSAuthCore
```

Why?  How do I get XCode to find frameworks in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CocoaPods Frameworks that I was trying to add were built only for iOS 11+, but my very old project had a deployment target of iOS 8.4.

Looking at error details in the Report Navigator as @paul-beusterien suggested was critical.  I found this:

`Ld /Users/dyoung/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-acdmyjbbrpbhlkfiyypetovwacrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/MyApp normal armv7 (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')`

The key thing there is the armv7 architecture.  This architecture is only part of the build process if you have a deployment target of 10.x or earlier but not if you have 11.x or later.  And if the frameworks you are including don't have armv7 architecture (e.g. if they are built for 11.0+), XCode gives very misleading error messages about the frameworks not being found.  What really isn't found is that specific architecture inside the framework.

Bottom line:  My problem had nothing to do with framework search paths.  Removing  $(PROJECT_DIR) from the framework search path only appeared to solve the problem by triggering a different compile-time problem to happen before it got to the linker problem.

The solution in this case is that I must change my deployment target to 11.0, then everything builds properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

- `pod deintegrate`
- Open the .xcodeproj
- Add the non-CocoaPods frameworks.
- `pod install`
- Open the .xcworkspace

Comment: Sadly, this yields the same result.  When I "Add the non-cocoaPods frameworks" by dragging them into "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content", XCode automatically adds the `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to the end of the Framework Search Paths.  Then when I run `pod install` I get the warning: `target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/MyApp.debug.xcconfig This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation.  
    - Use the $(inherited) flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.`  Build gives the same error.

Comment: Hmm, maybe something going on like spaces in a path or something else command line related. You could learn more by expanding the command line in the Report Navigator.

Comment: That was a simple but awesome tip about the Report Navigator, @paul-beusterien.  That revealed the true problem documented in a new answer I added.